# How do I make the build function wait until a button is pressed in an alert in init?

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to display an Alert that shows a disclaimer to the user as soon as the app is opened. The build method will run, that is the app will start its processing only after the user presses okay on the alert.

I've managed to show the alert in init using

```
   SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => AlertWindow().showAlert(context));
```

or

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => AlertWindows().showAlert(context));
```

This shows the alert, but the app starts building in the background. I want the app to run/build only after  `OKAY` button is pressed, and after the alert is popped.

Comment: I'm aware about another problem, that the alert won't display if Build waits, as it has no context if the build method does not run.

Comment: have you tried using an if statement inside the build method. and declare a variable indicating if the user pressed ok?

Comment: @SalmanAljabri Yes I have tried. What do I return in the else statement? I tried containing the if else statement inside a SetState Method but then the build method returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I implemented some code, you can try this code directly on **dartPad**  [Paste the code in this Editor](https://dartpad.dev/)

I used **setState**, if it is for real time project you can use  Providers or bloc, for performance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Widget viewHolder;

  void initState() {
    viewHolder = Container();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterPostFrameCallBack());
    super.initState();
  }

  afterPostFrameCallBack() {
    _showDialog();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return viewHolder;
  }

  Widget _buildView() {
    return Container(child: Text('This is after okay button'));
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("App Update Available"),
          content: Text(
              "We have fixed some issues and added some cool features in this update"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            FlatButton(
              child: new Text("ok"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                setState(() {
                  viewHolder = _buildView();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been stuck on this all morning, and this finally works. Thanks a ton!